# uniform resampling for MRI slices

Tags: matlab

I have contour of two MRI slices, I even know the pixel locations where these contours lie, the problem is to generate a slice between these two slices, and I know the length of the slice which has to obtained by interpolation. I want to resample the length of the two slices according to the middle interpolated slice, to will I be able to do it

Comment: @LuisMendo - Mentalist

Comment: What are "contours" of MRI slices?

Comment: outer edge of the MRI slice

Comment: Usually when someone asks for clarification, the intended effect is for the person to understand your problem more. You've made me more confused, which is the opposite effect. I think I'll refrain from answering any more questions or asking for clarification as I've tried doing this with you in the past to no avail.

Comment: ok I'l try to explain it full. I have two binary MRI image and I have already found its edge that is the circumference or boundary. I want to interpolate a third slice between these two. I know the length of the circumference of the middle third slice, and I want to bring  the circumference of 2 other slices equal to this third middle middle slice.